# Three20 in Xcode4 - Couldn't find the Frameworks children

Tags: iphone, xcode4, three20

I have Three20 in my Xcode 3 project and would like to upgrade the project with Xcode 4 (just installed).

I've followed [Three20's Xcode 4 Transition Guide](http://three20.info/article/2011-03-10-Xcode4-Support) and perform this command line:

```
> python three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p path/to/your/project/project.xcodeproj Three20 --xcode-version=4
```

but what I see is these errors:

```
ERROR:root:Couldn't find the Frameworks children.
ERROR:root:Couldn't find the Frameworks children.
ERROR:root:Couldn't find the Frameworks children.
ERROR:root:Couldn't find the Frameworks children.
ERROR:root:Couldn't find the Frameworks children.
ERROR:root:Couldn't find the Frameworks children.
ERROR:root:Couldn't find the Frameworks children.
ERROR:root:Couldn't find the Frameworks children.
ERROR:root:Some dependencies failed to be added:
ERROR:root: Three20Style:Three20Style

ERROR:root: Three20Network:Three20Network

ERROR:root: Three20UI:Three20UI

ERROR:root: Three20Core:Three20Core

ERROR:root: Three20UINavigator:Three20UINavigator

ERROR:root: Three20:Three20

ERROR:root: Three20UICommon:Three20UICommon
```

Do you know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that it's easier to "start over", rather than migrate.

- Remove any three20 projects from your project (they are usually under "Frameworks")
- Remove the old Three20.Bundle
- Search for "Three20" in the "Build Settings" and remove any reference to Three20

Now just run the Three20 command line to add Three20

```
> python three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p path/to/your/project/project.xcodeproj Three20
```